# Codesigning for the appstore

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, unity-game-engine

A friend of mine wrote a game using **unity** and I want to submit it to the Mac App Store.

When I codesign the bundle, it only codesigns the actual binary. As unity has quite some dependencies, of which one being monodevelop, there is some dylib included in the bundle. How do I include this binary properly in the code signature?

thanks.